# Extract emails from file with more than 100 users

Tags: linux, awk, sed, count, grep

I can't quite wrap my head around this issue. I'm trying to output a file with a list of email addresses from a list of email address. If there are more than 100 email addresses assigned to any given in that list domain i need those emails outputted those to a file.

emaillist.txt  file will have:

```
5000 occurrences of userID@yahoo.com 
2000 occurrences of userID@aol.com
100 occurrences of userID@rr.com  
10 occurrences of userID@whatever.com
```

`cut -d @ -f 2 emailist.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`

outputs

```
5000 yahoo.com 
2000 aol.com 
100 rr.com 
10 whatever.com
```

Now that i know the counts of how many emails i have at each domain, i only want the email addresses in the new file of domains that have more than 100 users.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. Its about helping people debug `if/else/endif` type coding problems. You'll have to show an attempt to solve  your problem to get some help. Edit  your question to show how you have tried to use the code in the other answer as a basis for a solution. basiclly we need to see sample input, required output from that sample, code, current output and exact error messages as well as any comments you can share about what is throwing your off. Good luck.

Comment: You need to show your sample input. You can't expect help if people have to guess your input files or record formats.

Comment: I dont understand your input. If `10 whatever.com` is printed, it's mean there is 10 occurences of whatever.com. But it's suposed to print only  `if >100`

Comment: well the files will have 5000 occurances of different userID@yahoo.com and 2000 userID@aol.com and userID@rr.com and userID@whatever.com

I want to be able to take all emails of domains that have more than 100 users and put them in a file. I don't want emails of domains with less than 100 users so all the userID@whatever.com will be excluded from the new file.

Comment: Give some sample input maybe. Sample output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
cut -d @ -f 2 email.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 >= 100 {print $2}' | while read e; do grep "@$e$" email.txt >> emailkeep.txt; done
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much pcantlupo. This will be mail me out of this qmail problem big time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contains emails only. Use the following `awk` would solve your problem.

```
awk '{split($0, a, "@");} NR==FNR{mp[a[2]]++; next} (mp[a[2]]>=100)' emaillist.txt  emaillist.txt
                                                            ^^^ modify to whatever you need
```

**DEMO**

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ cat emaillist.txt 
userID@yahoo.com 
userID1@yahoo.com 
userID2@yahoo.com 
userID@aol.com
userID@rr.com  
userID@whatever.com
lo@ubuntu:~$ awk '{split($0, a, "@");} NR==FNR{mp[a[2]]++; next} (mp[a[2]]>1)' emaillist.txt  emaillist.txt 
userID@yahoo.com 
userID1@yahoo.com 
userID2@yahoo.com
```

Comment: This works too - both solutions are elegant and thank you for taking the time to help me.